# Is this a bug in g++ or clang++

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

The following code:

```
class A
{
  friend class B;
  int m;
};

class B
{
  friend void f(A* p) { p->m = 32; }
};
```

Compiles in clang version 9.0.0-2, but not in g++ version 9.2.1

```
friend-test.cpp: In function ‘void f(A*)’:
friend-test.cpp:10:28: error: ‘int A::m’ is private within this context
   10 |   friend void f(A* p) { p->m = 32; }
      |                            ^
friend-test.cpp:5:7: note: declared private here
    5 |   int m;
      |       ^
```

Which compiler is right?

Answer (score 8):

GCC is in the right. Clang appears to have a bug.

> **[class.friend]**
>
> [10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.friend#10) Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class A {
>   friend class B;
>   int a;
> };
>
> class B {
>   friend class C;
> };
>
> class C  {
>   void f(A* p) {
>     p->a++;         // error: C is not a friend of A despite being a friend of a friend
>   }
> };
>
> class D : public B  {
>   void f(A* p) {
>     p->a++;         // error: D is not a friend of A despite being derived from a friend
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

The fact `f` is a friend of `B` and `B` is in turn a friend of `A` doesn't mean `f` is allowed to access `A`'s private parts.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (14.3 Friends)

> **10  Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive**

Thus the compiler clang has a bug.

It is interesting to note that if to define the function outside the `class B` like

```
class B
{
    public:
    friend void f(A* p);
};

void f(A* p) { p->m = 32; }
```

then in this case the compiler clang HEAD 10.0.0 issues an error

```
rog.cc:18:19: error: 'm' is a private member of 'A'
void f(A* p) { p->m = 32; }
                  ^
prog.cc:9:7: note: implicitly declared private here
  int m;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

So without any doubts the compiler has a bug.